# Apex Test Failure: null Internal Salesforce Error: 1795791051-15474 (1859615571) (1859615571)

Tags: gack

We have had an issue in the last couple of weeks with a package version create for our second generation package.  When I try and create a package version we are getting an error coming back saying.

Apex Test Failure: null Internal Salesforce Error: 1795791051-15474 (1859615571) (1859615571)

This is occurring with 2 of my test classes, which have not changed between now and the last successful package release.

I am able to get an error in my scratch org, but only the first time the test classes are run after creating a scratch org.  After it has failed once the test classes run without issue.  Also it will only fail on one of the test classes at a time.  If I include both one always passes and one fails.

I am starting to suspect that there is something missing in the scratch org that is not refreshed until this test class is run, but then is fine after.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

I have logged a case with Salesforce Support and they have sent me the error from the logs which is:

Run Time Expection with message as " Detected a stale policy and it is getting refreshed"

This is a known Salesforce Issue

Behavior reported by Salesforce R&D Team:

"Errors are currently occurring for scratch orgs where the first run of some tests fail due to Unknown Exception"